# SVG not showing up when added to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I am having a very interesting issue, where when I add new SVG elements to a div, only the first time the append is called does a new svg element show up. They work when hard coded, but when they are added onmousedown, they don't show up, even though they are added to the HTML file. I am assuming that it is a problem of my understanding of SVG, and that elements can't be added dynamically, but I have been looking around the internet, and can't find anything on the subject.

You can see that on the $(document).mousedown function, a new circle is appended to the svg holder, however even though it is added to the SVG holder, it will not show up on the web page.

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div id="svgHolder">
    <!--THIS CIRCLE SHOWS UP-->
    <svg><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' fill='red' /></svg>
</div>
```

JQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var mouse={
    x:0,
    y:0,
    drawing:false,
    lastX:0,
    lastY:0,

}

$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    console.log('md')
    mouse.x=e.clientX
    mouse.y=e.clientY
    mouse.drawing=true
            //THIS CIRCLE WILL BE ADDED TO THE SVGHOLDER, BUT WILL NOT SHOW UP
    $("#svgHolder").append("<svg><circle cx='"+mouse.x+"' cy='"+mouse.y+"' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' fill='red' /></svg>");
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    console.log('mu')
    mouse.x=e.clientX
    mouse.y=e.clientY
    mouse.drawing=false
});



$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log('mm')
    mouse.x=e.clientX
    mouse.y=e.clientY
});



});
```

Comment: Maybe try adding the namespace to the `svg` tag. Like so.. `$("#svgHolder").append('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx= ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `svg` is being inserted but out of your viewport so you can't see it, add some `width` and `height` to the `svg` and also set a proper value for `cx` and `cy` properties, i.e.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    $("#svgHolder")
    .append("<svg width='100' height='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' fill='red' /></svg>");
});
```

Also remember `clientX` and `clientY` gives the coordinates relative to the viewport in CSS pixels.

[Example1](http://jsbin.com/ejisop/1/edit), [Example2](http://jsbin.com/ejisop/5/edit) and [more about SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement).

Comment: +1 - either set an explicit width/height on the svg or resize the container div.

Answer (score 7):

I think that when you dynamically create a `svg` node you have to create the namespace.

```
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
$(svg).append("<circle ...");
```