# Element created with createElementNS doesn't show

Tags: javascript, svg, appendchild

I'm trying to create a new  `<img>` with the `<svg>` tag with JavaScript every time I click on the button. When I see the result in the console firebug it works correctly, but nothing on screen displays.
What I want is for an image `<svg>` to appear after the last one every time you click the button.

Thanks in advance.

```
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 

mybtn.addEventListener("click", createCircleSVG);


    function createCircleSVG(){
      var d = document.createElement('svg');
      d.setAttribute('id','mySVG');

      document.getElementById("svgContainer").appendChild(d); 
      createCircle();
    }    

function createCircle(){

        var myCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle"); //to create a circle."
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","mycircle" + opCounter++);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",25);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",25);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",100);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","blue");

        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle);
    }
```

Comment: Similar question with same answer: [SVG not showing up when added to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691424/svg-not-showing-up-when-added-to-html) "Your svg is being inserted but out of your viewport so you can't see it, add some width and height to the svg..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a SVG:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
```

First function:

```
function createSVG() { ... }
```

Second function:

```
function createSVGCircle() { createSVG() ... }
```

Or separated:

```
createSVG();
createSVGCircle();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahdk3ea7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the svg element in the SVG namespace using createElementNS (like you already do for the circle) e.g.

```
var d = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
```

giving the SVG element a width and height is also necessary

```
    d.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    d.setAttribute("height", "100%");
```

Note here we can use setAttribute as the attributes are in the null namespace. You can convert the circle setAttributeNS calls too if you want.